# iPhone RCA APIs for communication with apps

Tags: ios, iphone, serial-port

What API are available for communicating between a native device/web app and the devices RCA port, like the way credit card readers (square, paypal etc.) exist for iPhones?

**Does anyone know what sound/recording API is used by these readers to encode data as audio?**

Answer (score 2):

The card reader plays an audio encoding of the card data, and the app is listening to the audio. So technically it's using audio recording APIs. There's no way to treat the headphone jack like a serial port and read data over it, only audio. If you wish to communicate directly with another device, either it needs to be over bluetooth or thru the dock/lightning connector.